# Unable to authenticate Kibana to Elasticsearch on v8.0.1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I've been attempting to establish authentication between Kibana and Elasticsearch version 8.0.1, using the "kibana_system" user. Unfortunately, I've encountered a 401 error. My Elasticsearch instance is a single-node setup running within a Docker container on a virtual machine (VM). I've configured security for Elasticsearch using PEM format. I'd greatly appreciate any guidance on identifying what might be causing this issue. I've attached my Kibana Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files for reference.

Error log from kibana container

```
`[DEBUG][elasticsearch.query.data] 401 - 633.0B
2023-09-16T16:08:05.703008000Z GET /_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip [security_exception]: unable to authenticate user [kibana_system] for REST request [/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip]`
```

Error log from Elasticsearch docker container

```
log.level":"DEBUG", "message":"Authentication of [kibana_system] using realm [reserved/reserved] with token [UsernamePasswordToken] was [AuthenticationResult{status=TERMINATE, value=null, message=failed to authenticate user [kibana_system], exception=null}]", "ecs.version":
```

Kibana Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

```
RUN echo "CERT_PASS" | openssl pkcs12 -in /etc/kibana/ssl/CERT_NAME -out /etc/kibana/ssl/elasticsearch-http-ca.crt -cacerts -nokeys -chain -passin stdin
RUN echo "CERT_PASS" | openssl pkcs12 -in /etc/kibana/ssl/CERT_NAME -clcerts -nokeys -out /etc/kibana/ssl/kb-cert.crt -passin stdin -passout pass:"CERT_PASS"
RUN echo "CERT_PASS" | openssl pkcs12 -in /etc/kibana/ssl/CERT_NAME -nocerts -out /etc/kibana/ssl/kb-key.key -nodes -passin stdin


USER kibana

################### Kibana Docker compose #############################################
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS="https://127.0.0.1:9200"
      - SERVER_HOST="0.0.0.0"
      - LOGGING_ROOT_LEVEL=debug
      - XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=TRUE
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=KIBANA_SYSTEM
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD="KIBANA_PASWORD"
      - XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY="key"
      - XPACK_REPORTING_ENCRYPTIONKEY="key"
      - XPACK_REPORTING_ROLES_ENABLED=FALSE
      - SERVER_SSL_ENABLED=true
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFICATIONMODE=certificate
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=/etc/kibana/ssl/elasticsearch-http-ca.crt
      - SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATE=/etc/kibana/ssl/kb-cert.crt
      - SERVER_SSL_KEY=/etc/kibana/ssl/kb-key.key
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```

elasticsearch docker-compose file

```
 environment:
      - cluster.name=es-0
      - node.name=es-0
      - discovery.seed_hosts=127.0.0.1
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es-0
      - network.host=_site_,_local_
      - node.roles=master,data
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD="ELASTIC_PASWORD"
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - path.repo=/usr/share/
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/ssl/kb-key.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/ssl/kb-cert.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/ssl/elasticsearch-http-ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=/usr/share/elasticsearch/ssl/kb-key.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=/usr/share/elasticsearch/ssl/kb-cert.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=/usr/share/elasticsearch/ssl/elasticsearch-http-ca.crt
```

I also tried to authenticate with elasticsearch service account on docker-compose.yml. However, it is not working either.

```
ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN="servicetoken"
```

Error on kibana container

```
[DEBUG][elasticsearch.query.data] 401 - 595.0B
2023-09-21T10:03:21.102255000Z GET /_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip [security_exception]: error attempting to authenticate request
```

I also see this type of error on the logs

```
io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: [.security] org.elasticsearch.index.IndexNotFoundException: no such index [.security]\n\tat
```